# Как делать вставку JSON данных в Postgres?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate

Есть объект `Phrase` который имеет поле представленное как `JSON` объект, но при попытке записать его в колонку с соответствующим типом падает:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "phrase"
>   is of type json but expression is of type bytea   Подсказка: You will
>   need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Сам объект:

```
public class Phrase {
    private int id;
    private PGobject phrase;

    public Phrase() {
    }

    public Phrase(int id, String phraseVal) throws SQLException {
        this.id = id;
        phrase = new PGobject();
        phrase.setType("json");
        phrase.setValue(phraseVal);
    }
    ...геттеры и сеттеры...
}
```

Метод добавления в базу:

```
public void addPhrase(final Phrase phrase) {

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(phrase);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

А вызываю я это так:

```
final Phrase phrase = new Phrase(1, new Gson().toJson(mapWithDataForJson));

new DAOImpl(factory).addPhrase(phrase);
```

И вроде "танец с бубном" для кастинга в Postgres-json формат я исполнил но что-то все равно идет не так. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Как мне записать произвести вставку json поля?

Решение

```
phrase = new PGobject();
phrase.setType("json");
phrase.setValue(phraseVal);
```

Взято вот из этого вопроса (**предпоследний ответ**):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844138/how-can-i-insert-json-object-into-postgres-using-java-preparedstatement

И на всякий случай таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phrases (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
    phrase JSON NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```